# Das Patent gehörte ihm entzogen

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Noch eine Frage übers Buch *Das Parfum* von Patrick Süskind. Im folgenden Ausschnitt beklagt sich eine Figur (innerlich) über einen Konkurrenten im Duftgewerbe:

> Man wünschte sich die drakonischsten Maßnahmen gegen diesen
> Ausderreihetanzer, gegen diesen Duftinflationär. **Das Patent gehörte
> ihm entzogen**, ein saftiges Berufsverbot auferlegt …, und überhaupt
> sollte der Kerl erst einmal eine Lehre machen!

Ich verstehe die grammatikalische Rolle von "gehörte" nicht. Ich glaube, dass die Figur davon fantasiert, wie ein Patent, das dem Konkurrenten gehört, diesem Konkurrenten entzogen würde. Wenn ich Recht habe, würde ich dann denken, dass die Konstruktion wäre: "Das ihm gehörende Patent ihm entzogen," oder was Ähnliches. Eine Erklärung dazu wäre hilfreich.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Das Beispiel verwendet das Verb "gehören" in einer sehr schönen, aber wohl etwas altertümlichen Weise. Abstrakt formuliert bedeutet die Konstruktion "jemand gehört" + (Verb im Partizip), dass etwas einer Person angemessen ist, dass ihr etwa "gebührt" - durchaus auch etwas Negatives. Das Verb wird hier also ***nicht*** in seiner häufigsten Verwendung, nämlich der rechtlichen Zuordnung (Eigentum/Besitz) eingesetzt. Umgangssprachlich hört man auch heute noch etwa

> Der gehört geschlagen!

wenn jemand etwas sehr Dummes gemacht hat. Gemeint ist, dass der betreffenden Person Schläge als angemessene Strafe gebühren. Genauso:

> Dem gehört der Führerschein entzogen!

um auszudrücken, dass jemand besser nicht weiterhin am Straßenverkehr teilnehmen dürfen sollte.

Das Beispiel in der Frage ist analog aufgebaut:

> Ihm gehört das Patent entzogen

bedeutet schlicht, dass die Person quasi ihre Gewerbeerlaubnis verlieren soll. Ich verstehe Patent hier nicht in dem technischen Sinn eines gewerblichen Schutzes, den das Patentamt erteilt. Vielmehr soll die betroffene Person die Möglichkeit verlieren, weiterhin als Parfümeur tätig zu sein. Inhaltlich ist das praktisch identisch mit dem Folgesatz (Berufsverbot).

Comment: Duden und DWDS klassifizieren das als vor allem süddeutsch und österreichisch.

Comment: @CarstenS: Als ein in Südwestdeutschland Aufgewachsener nehme ich die Formulierung in der Tat auch nicht wirklich als "altertümlich" wahr. Als nettes Beispiel kann man auch auch auf den Slogan eines Radiosenders verweisen, der "<Name> gehört gehört!" lautet (es ist ein SWR-irgendwas, kann mir die Nummern nie merken). Das erste "gehört" ist das hier diskutierte (und das zweite einfach das Partizip Perfekt von "hören").

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Das war nicht SWR-irgendwas, sondern der österreichische Sender Ö1: "Ö1 gehört gehört". Das ist der Klassik-Sender des ORF

Comment: Das "Patent" ist hier als Befähigung(snachweis) zu verstehen, analog zu "Kapitänspatent" oder "Offizierspatent".

Comment: @bakunin: Interessant, offenbar verwendeten sowohl Ö1 als auch (später) SWR1 denselben Slogan: https://www.radioszene.de/36600/swr-1-baden-wuerttemberg-reichweite-mit-melodie.html (s. Grafik bei der Überschrift "doppelter Claim")

Comment: Beispiel aus dem Mannheimer Dialekt: "Der ghert oigsperrt!" (Der gehört eingesperrt!). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NhTydjhgmBA

Comment: Ähnliche Verwendungen von "gehören" gibt es auch in Formulierung wie "Es gehört sich (nicht), dies und jenes zu tun" oder "Das ist ungehörig!".

Answer (score 3):

> Ihm gehört der Führerschein entzogen.

Bei *gehören* + Partizip 2 handelt es sich um ein modales Passiv mit ähnlicher Bedeutung wie *sein* + zu-Infinitiv.

> Ihm ist der Führerschein zu entziehen.
> "Man sollte/müsste ihm den Führerschein entziehen."

Laut [Atlas Alltagssprache](https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r11-f3f/) ist diese Konstruktion im Süden Deutschlands verbreiteter als im Norden. Meiner Ansicht handelt es sich allerdings nicht um einen Regionalismus oder Umgangssprache; dafür sind Zeitungsbelege zu häufig. Einige Beispiele (via [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=public&q=%40geh%C3%B6rt%20%24p%3DVVPP)):

> Eine Sauerei gehört bestraft!
> Der Paragraph gehört abgeschafft.
> Dieser Schrottreaktor gehört abgeschaltet.
> So etwas gehört verfilmt.
> Die NPD gehört verboten!